# Possibility of deadlock with dispatch_async in asynchronous connection completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

Is it possible that using `dispatch_async()` to the main queue inside an `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous request completion handler can cause a deadlock?

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 // Alsways perform such code on the main queue/thread
                 /// At this point I update the UI
             });

         }
     }];
```

If yes, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why your code should dead-lock. But there might be a misunderstanding
about the `queue` parameter. That is the queue on which the *completion block* is 
executed, not the queue that is used for loading the data in the background.

`sendAsynchronousRequest` does always load the data on a background queue and does not block the main thread.
Therefore, to execute the completion handler on the main thread, you don't need
to create a operation queue, and you can simplify your code to:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     // This is executed on the main thread.
     // Update UI elements ...
     if (error) {

     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a deadlock with `dispatch_async`. It doesn't block the calling queue.

Comment: True.  Basically and always this is true ;)

Comment: But it obtains a lock (`_pthread_rwlock_lock_slow`) and if this lock cannot be obtained, as some other thread has it and for some reason won't release it, then it can deadlock. I'm facing such a problem right now. All my `dispatch_async` deadlock as they fail to obtain the lock of the queue that is required for safely adding blocks to it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to run the `NSURLConnection` off the main queue and then update the UI on the main queue.  This is a good idea.  But you get all that for free with the method.  The `queue` parameter says where the completion block should be dispatched...

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        // this will run on the main queue because of the queue param
        // update the ui
    }
}];
```